# WindowsMachineFileCopy doesn't copy *EXTRA Files

Tags: azure-devops, devops, robocopy, azure-devops-self-hosted-agent

I am attempting to setup new releases in our new Azure DevOps (AzDo) environment.  We have on prem agents setup with rights to access the destination servers with 1 agent per environment. (Dev -> Test -> Prod)  We noticed that the release was "failing" even though it was showing as successful because both CopyFiles and WindowsMachineFileCopy don't copy new files.   My questions are thus:

1. It looks like SSH File copy is the task I have to use?
2. Is there a simpler way to just force one of the other tasks to copy all files?
3. Is there another existing task I can use for this?
4. I do not understand the wisdom of not copying new files.  Everything I've seen written assumes this wisdom without explaining it.  What am I missing?

Comment: Hi there, please check whether my answer below can help you. If not, could you please provide some screen shots about the copy files task and its running log, so that people can investigate the question further. Please be careful to remove your personal information when providing screenshots~

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried on my side but the CopyFile task copy new files or *EXTRA file successfully.

Here is some troubleshooting advice:

1. If the file you want to copy already exists in the destination folder, check the "Overwrite" option in "Advanced".
2. Check the value of the "Contents". `*` copies all files in the specified source folder and `**` copies all files in the specified source folder and all files in all sub-folders. In addition, the pattern is used to match only file paths, not folder paths. So you should specify patterns such as `**\bin\**` instead of `**\bin`.